# Wordpress generate link tag

Tags: wordpress

I create a wordpress theme with html5blank and my html pages.

I have a problem and I couldn't find the solution :

When I copy paste my code in one page, wordpress generate some links in my code...

I filmed my screen to explain the problem : https://youtu.be/x87cFOMvKiI

Thank you very much